# Remove or disable attribute download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have a tag with download attribute:

```
<a href="#" id="dl-btn" download>click to download</a>
```

then depending if the download is available in the script I set values:

```
if(download_exist)$('#dl-btn').attr('href', path).prop('download', true);
else $('#dl-btn').attr('href', '#').prop('download', 'disabled');
```

but it still downloads html page (like index.html)

I tried:

```
$('#dl-btn').attr('href', '#').removeProp('download');

$('#dl-btn').attr('href', '#').prop('download', false);
```

Nothing seems to preventing it trigger download (at least in chrome)

Comment: There is no `disabled` attribute on `a` elements. Try `removeAttr('download')`

Comment: Check 'can I use' if still developing for IE11 (and before): http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use removeAttr   `removeAttr('download');`

Comment: Why doesnt it work with removeProp? But it works if I add it with prop : .prop('download', true);

Comment: @Toniq you can read more about prop and attr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr